# Is it possible to roll-back/downgrade from Android 6 to 5.1.1 without loosing all data and installed applications?

Tags: ota-update, 6.0-marshmallow, downgrade

I tapped "Install" on a system update notification on my Nexus 7 2013. This update is the worst thing I've ever seen since Android Lollipop came out with all of it's bugs. The home button swipe-up Google Now action is gone, notification bar rolls down from wherever you put your finger when swiping down, toasts and pop-up notifications are annoying you with permissions all the time and all animations are extremely laggy. So how do I downgrade my tablet back to 5.1.1 without loosing all my data or using a PC(my GPU is currently on RMA).

Comment: No. As far as I know, Lollipop->Marshmallow dirty flashes are problematic, to say the least. You could try your luck, however.

Comment: So, doing the reverse would be even more problematic, to say the least.

Comment: No way. Even if it were usually possible, all the permissions changes would make it even worse.